# Elasticsearch sort date after aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-aggregation

I need to find related or similar posts and then sort them by date. How can I do that?
here is a query :

```
     {
  "fields":[
    "id", "score"
  ],
  "size":0,
  "query":{
    "function_score":{
      "query":{
        "bool":{
          "should":[
            { "match":{ "main_headline.en":{"query":"some text"}}},
            {"match":{"body.en":"some text" }}
          ],
          "must_not":{ "term":{  "id":76484 }}
        }
      },
      "functions":[
        {
          "gauss":{
            "published_at":{ "scale":"140w","decay":0.3
            }
          }
        }]
    }
  },
  "aggregations":{
    "postslug":{
      "terms":{
        "field":"slug",
        "size":9,
        "order":{"max_score":"desc"}
      },
      "aggs":{
        "max_score":{
          "max":{ "script":"_score" }
        },
        "fields":{
          "top_hits":{
            "size":1,
            "_source":{
              "includes":["id", "published_at", "slug"]
            }
          }
        },
        "aggs":{
          "byDate":{
            "max":{"field":"published_at"}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried achieved via sub-aggregation - `byDate` but I got an error `Could not find aggregator type [byDate] in [aggs]. How I can fix this error or how I can sort the data after aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting tells that Elasticsearch couldn't find `byDate` aggregation type, which I suppose you intended to be the name of the aggregation (see [this section of the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-aggregations.html#_structuring_aggregations) for more details).

In the example you provided `aggs` is on the same level as `fields` and ES interprets it as a name of another sub-aggregation. Probably you would like to move that `aggs` under `fields`.

Since you are using `top_hits` then you can use the built-in [`sort`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html#_options_2) option.

Hope that helps!